# What is an example of an integral that CANNOT be done without contour integration ? If that exist.

Tags: integration, contour-integration

What is an example of an indefinite integral that CANNOT be done without contour integration ? If that exist.

Im talking about closed forms for integrals, not numerical methods.

Note that there are many tricks to do an integral. As a reference to some less common techniques, I give a link

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

Note however that this link talks about definite integrals mainly, where my question is about indefinite integrals.

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by "...CANNOT be done without contour integration"?

Comment: Do you allow numerical integration as a method?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The only way we are able to evaluate/prove the value(closed form) of the integral is by using contour integration. Hence it cannot be done without contour integration.

Comment: @CalvinLin No that is not allowed.